# Why does not IE supports my special-character blocker script in my input fields?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, filter, special-characters, keypress

My script is this:

```
var emailmask = /^[a-z0-9.]/g;

function restrictCharacters(myfield, e, restrictionType) {
if (!e) var e = window.event
if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
else if (e.which) code = e.which;
var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
if (code==27) { this.blur(); return false; }
if (!e.ctrlKey && code!=9 && code!=8 && code!=36 && code!=37 && code!=38 && (code!=39 || (code==39 && character=="'")) && code!=40) {
    if (character.match(restrictionType)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

The input:

```
<input type="text" name="fx_username" value="asd" id="username" class="normal email need" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(this, event, emailmask);"/>
```

It simply does not work with IE, but FF, chrome is okay. Could you help me in this case please?

Edit: The does not work means, it does not stripped the special characters like @{}¤$ß.

Comment: Define "does not work". What happens?

Comment: Your regex is horrible for email validation btw.. what if I have `-` or `_` or `+` (yes, this is perfectly valid) in my email address?

Comment: You shouldn’t use magic numbers; better use the constants of [KeyEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20000901/events.html#Events-KeyEvent) instead.

Comment: The code in general is nigh unreadable in fact. And you say it's a special blocker but it's actually a special acceptor.

Comment: The full range of allowed email addresses in RFC 822 as a regex is here : http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html for only the address part there is a good analysis here : http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php anything less and either you aren't correctly filtering or are refusing customers due to their mail address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't always have a return-value.
If this condition :

```
if (!e.ctrlKey && code!=9 && code!=8 && code!=36 && code!=37 && code!=38 && (code!=39 || (code==39 && character=="'")) && code!=40)
```

doesn't match, it will return nothing. Looks like the behaviour is different in browsers. In MSIE I think it's somehow not evaluated to false.

Solution: add this at the end of the function:

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

That function is incorrect in several ways.

1. You shouldn't use `var` on the parameter "e" in that first line.  The conventional way to write that is

   e = e || window.event;

   However, in this case it won't really work properly anyway, because the code in your "onkeypress" attribute value *assumes* that it can use `window.event`.  That's incorrect and won't work in Firefox.
2. You did not define "code" as a local variable with `var`.
3. The code makes the assumption that `this` will be set to the element, when in fact the first parameter ("myfield") is the only thing referring to the element.
4. If that long, long "if" test fails, the function returns `undefined`.
5. <s>The regular expression is incorrect.  It matches any character at the beginning of a string, because you've got "." in the brackets.  Also that "g" modifier is unnecessary.</s> (fixed) (though I would suggest using "regexp.test(string)" instead because its probably a little faster)

It's a little hard to say what it is you want the code to do here, but until all those errors get fixed there's no clear way to say how to improve it .